# MySQL finding similar data in 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, database

So I have a database with 2 tables, Movies, and PS3.
Each contains titles.
I got the Movie titles from the IMDB list of titles based on Video games. Not all of them have the same title as the game they are based, but may have a word or two similar.

I was wondering how would I go about using the titles on ps3 and comparing it to the Movies.
I want to return the similar items.

For example, Resident Evil: Apocalypse is a film, there is no game called Resident Evil: Apocalypse, but there is Resident Evil games on the PS3 with different names, so would like to get that data.

How could I go about this? I tried doing

```
WHERE ps3.titles LIKE '%movie.titles%'
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm not even sure if it is possible in MySQL.
Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall matching is a tall order. But in terms of syntax, consider this:

```
WHERE ps3.titles LIKE CONCAT('%',movie.titles,'%')
```

MySQL will see `movie.title` as an identifier (e.g. as a reference to a column in a table referenced in the query). The `'%'` are literals, the `CONCAT` strings the literals together with the value from the column, and then the LIKE comparison operator can be evaluated.

---

The comparison of close strings is whole big sticky ball of wax.

In terms of what's available in MySQL, it's very limited.

The MyISAM engine has `FULLTEXT` indexes, which can be useful for finding rows by "keyword"  matches. (There's a lower bound limit on the length of strings that will be indexed and considered a "match". I think the default is 4 characters, which eliminates words like "A", "of" and "the".)

MySQL also has the `REGEXP` comparison operator, which is more powerful than the `LIKE` comparison operator; but you'd have to manually craft your own comparisons.

The `SOUNDEX` function is also useful for identifying "close" matches... like matching "Apocalypse" with "Apokalyps"; but I don't think that would help you match "Apocalypse" with "Rewind: The Apocalyse Chronicles".

Any matching on just Title will be limited, and imprecise. You'll get some matches, and the more matches you get, the more are not going to be right.

Comment: @Thanks for the reply. That certainly matches a lot of them anyway. Thanks. How would you recommend making it better? Like right now it matches simple words like 'A', or 'Air' etc, would I probably have to do something in Java to make this better?